# react native status bar not displaying dark-content

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, statusbar

I am using the following code, though the status bar appears to be displaying white text instead of black. Any help would be great

```
// @flow

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, StatusBar } from 'react-native'
import NavigationRouter from '../Navigation/NavigationRouter'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import StartupActions from '../Redux/StartupRedux'
import ReduxPersist from '../Config/ReduxPersist'

// Styles
import styles from './Styles/RootContainerStyle'

class RootContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    // if redux persist is not active fire startup action
    if (!ReduxPersist.active) {
      this.props.startup()
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.applicationView}>
        <StatusBar barStyle='dark-content' />
        <NavigationRouter />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

// wraps dispatch to create nicer functions to call within our component
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  startup: () => dispatch(StartupActions.startup())
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(RootContainer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue ended up being 2 root containers and the incorrect one was being updated